# Windows phone app test on difference devices

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I just made a Windows phone app and tested it on HTC Windows phone. Since there're multiple manufacturers out there, such as Nokia, Samsung, do I need to test on all of them to make sure the app work fine? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as testing goes it's most important that it works on a Windows 7 phone as well as the emulator. Device specific concerns are not as real as they were with previous Windows Phone operating systems. The WP7 devices are all standardized - even the resolution of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In theory - you may not, but in real life there are some shades. First of all it would be useful to test application in different screens' sizes (3.5"-4.7") some elements can be extremely small for touch in 3.5". Phones of the first wave have old processors so when i.e. Lumia 800 draws UI quickly, the, let's say, Omnia 7 can do it slower with lags.

Also is very strange thing I figured out for myself - many bugs are reproduces only on the HTC Mozart o_O. Also don't forget to test your application in the emulator with 256mb of ram.